# Excel 2016 create a tracking file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have multiple excel files (one for each month) that record the status of a given action. The status can be "Scheduled, Defferred, Fail, Success".

Currently I am loading the data straigh into Excel via a Data Source and Create a pivot table from there. Unfortunately, pivot table does not put the cell value it only counts the values which is helpful but not 100% what I need.

What I am trying to achieve is to get a table with all objects and their status in any given month.

example:

```
Object | Month 1 | Month 2| Month 3
Object1| Fail    | Success| Success
Object2| Fail    | Fail   | Fail
```

Each month corresponds to a Excel file ( this is fine with the Data Source).
Without getting into Macro creation (I'm not proficient at it) is there any way I could do this with Excel?

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

Using the suggestion to have it in tabular form generates the following:

```
Object | Status | Month 1 | Month 2 |Month 3
Object1| Sucess |    1    |         |
Object1| Fail   |         |     1   |   1
Object2| Success|    1    |     1   |
```

This is far harder to read, especially when I have close to 1000 lines. 
My goal is to have it easy enough that I can pull data from this report easily.

Comment: put whatever you had in the `values' section of the pivot table into the 'rows' section, and display everything in tabular form with no sub totals, this way you can show the exact values as opposed to a count of values

Comment: Thank for the quick feedback. I did try that, but what I get is empty table. On the header I get Month. The first column I get all objects and associate status. But the table itself is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going at this in the wrong direction in the end. I do not need to have a Pivot table but while importing the data, I can actually treat it in a way that will create the table as I want.

As a final set of setting up my data source, I select the column that has the files names (Month.xlsx), Select Transform (tab), Pivot Column.

Then I just need to select that I want the values for Status and to not Aggregate the values.
The resulting table has exactly what I was looking for.